# Postponing component mounting unless I return true

Tags: reactjs, session, redux, redux-saga

I have a controller called `PersonCreate`. In this component, I have to check the role of the authenticated user (`this.props.app.session.user.role.isAdmin()`) and depending on the value, render some form.

The problem is, it takes a while to generate the session object. When I browse the endpoint for `http://.../person/create`, it tries to call `this.props.app.session.user.role.isAdmin()`, which throws null pointer exception because session is not generated yet.

My Router file looks like this.

```
class RootComponent extends React.Component<any, any> {

  private generateSession() {
    store.dispatch(SessionActions.generate());
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
          <Route path="app" onEnter={this.generateSession}>
            <Route path="person">
              <Route path="create" component={PersonCreate} />
              <Route path="update/:id" component={PersonUpdate} />
              <Route path="delete/:id" component={PersonDelete} />

     ...
```

Basically `store.dispatch(SessionActions.generate())` generated a `Saga` which does a series of asyncronous stuff. (e.g validate token, obtain session information, refresh local storage etc.) I have to start rendering components after they complete.

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem you are looking at is called `Render Hijacking`. You can google about it. The best way to do this is via `HOC`. Readmore on it [here](https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e). Once you read through, if u have any issues, get back to us.

Answer (score 1):

You can use check in RootComponent like this:

```
public render() {
  if (!this.props.app.session) {
    return null;
  }
```

and it will render routes only after session will be initialized.

Or you can use similar check in `PersonCreate` component.

Comment: It has to render some routes without authentication too. (e.g signin) Already tried this one.

Comment: As I mentioned, you can use such check inside `PersonCreate` then or any other component

Comment: That is not a good solution though. I cannot duplicate the same logic in hundreds of components.

Comment: You can add some function or HOC as was mentioned in comment. Anyway there are possibilities to follow DRY principle. But basically you need to check if variable is exists, in some place

Answer (score 0):

You can create a React Component that contains login for rendering. This component wraps all of the routes that require users information.

```
<Route path=”/” component={App}>
  <Route path=”cart” component={Cart}/>
  <Route path=”login” component={Login}/>

  <Route component={EnsureLoggedInContainer}>
    <Route path=”checkout” component={Checkout}/>
    <Route path=”account” component={Account}/>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

And in this "parent"(EnsureLoggedInContainer) component in render do something like:

```
  render() {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      return <AppropriateUserForm />;
    } else {
      return <LoadingIndicator />;
    }
  }
```

You can read more about this approach here:
https://medium.com/the-many/adding-login-and-authentication-sections-to-your-react-or-react-native-app-7767fd251bd1